# Flex Download File with POST method

Tags: java, apache-flex

I have implemented file download functionality in my application

```
navigateToURL(urlRequest,"_blank");
```

I am using navigateToURL method to call servlet in Java backed but in that case my URL contains values as in that URL request i am passing values in string and through get method i am downloading that file.
(like path of a file) so i need to hide that as it is security concern , please share your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST in Flex setting URLRequestMethod.POST to URLRequest.method();
This will hide your parameters from the eye, it's not a security solution, though.